# Length of a curve (?) tangent to a circle

Tags: geometry, contest-math

I'm preparing for my (hopefully) future university's entrance exams, and one example question reads as follows:

In the cargo bed of a truck with width *2d* a tube with radius *R* is placed as seen in the picture below. The cargo bed itself also has a height of *R*. A belt is attached over the tube, perpendicular to the length direction of the tube and the cargo bed, with its ends at points *A* and *B*, on the edges of the cargo bed. Which expression displays the length of the belt?

[image: image provided with the problem]

(A) $~2R \cdot \arcsin\left(\frac{R}{d}\right)+2\cdot\sqrt{d^2-R^2}$

(B) $~2R \cdot \arcsin\left(\frac{R}{d}\right)+2\cdot\sqrt{d^2+R^2}$

(C) $~2R \cdot \arccos\left(\frac{R}{d}\right)+2\cdot\sqrt{d^2-R^2}$

(D) $~2R \cdot \arccos\left(\frac{R}{d}\right)+2\cdot\sqrt{d^2+R^2}$

I quite frankly have no idea how to approach this problem, and it's the first real roadblock I've encountered on the example tests. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

[image]

$1)$ Find $x$ using Pythagoras.

$2)$ Calculate $\theta$.

$3)$ Use the formula for arc length to calculate the length of the curved part in the middle.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now!

Answer (score 1):

**Cheating:**

The first terms relate to the curved part and the second to the straight part, by Pythagoras.

If $d$ tends to infinity, the first term must vanish, and that excludes C and D.

Then the belt must be longer than $2d$, so A.